# IOS Переключение на другой язык в приложении

Tags: ios, app

У меня проект в котором все строки локализованы и используется NSLocalizedString. Приложение само выбирает язык в соответствии с языком системы, но мне нужно реализовать переключение вручную. как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

У функции `NSLocalizedString` очень много аргументов, хотя у многих из них есть значение по умолчанию. Так как Вы не предоставили никакого кода в вопросе, то смею предположить, что Вы используете её вот так:

```
NSLocalizedString("key", comment: "")
```

В таком случае Вы не используете аргумент `bundle`, который отвечает за пакет, из которого будут извлекаться переводы. И это плохо, без него Вам будет сложно управлять языками для переводов.

Предположим, что для описания языков Вы используете такое перечисление:

```
enum Language: String {

    case en
    case ru
}
```

Тогда переключение языков можно попробовать выполнить с помощью такой функции:

```
func switchApplicationLanguage(language: Language) {

    UserDefaults.standard.set([language.rawValue], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Основная идея заключается в том, что функция `NSLocalizedString` при выборе языка для перевода использует `UserDefaults`. В нашем случае мы устанавливаем 1 предпочитаемый язык. Однако опыт показывает, что установленные таким образом языки подхватываются лишь при следующем запуске приложения. Я не думаю, что пользователи оценят по достоинству необходимость перезапуска приложения каждый раз после изменения языка. Поэтому рекомендую использовать следующий вариант вызова `NSLocalizedString`:

```
NSLocalizedString("key", bundle: selectedBundle, comment: "")
```

Переменная `selectedBundle` вычисляется следующим образом:

```
var selectedBundle: Bundle {

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLanguage.rawValue, ofType: "lproj"),
       let bundle = Bundle(path: path) {

        return bundle
    }
    return Bundle.main
}
```

Выбранный язык у Вас должен храниться в глобальной переменной:

```
var currentLanguage: Language = .ru
```